# JMS: how can I enqueue a task that have failed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, queue, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using spring boot and I have a task which consists on invoking an external API to create a resource. In other words, it's just an API call which take a simple parameter.

Since that call is asynchronous, i need to ENSURE that the resource is created. So if the first call to the api fails, it has to be enqueued in order to retry after X seconds. Once the api call completes successfuly, i have to remove that api call from the queue.

How can i achieve this behaviour? I was looking for using ActiveMQ. Is there any other proposal which could work better with spring boot?

Comment: Using ActiveMQ for your use case is overkill, try considering Java's multi-threading API like executor service where you can schedule a thread to run after 'x' seconds etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "browse" and "get".

The steps as follows:

1. Browse data and run your api to create a resource. (data is not
   removed just browse it)
2. Check resource has been created and get a
   data from queue using selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use schedulerSupport of ActiveMQ, It is enabled by setting the broker schedulerSupport attribute to true :

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
```

http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

```
package com.example.amq;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ScheduledMessage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ProducerScheduledMessage implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        send("LOCAL_Q", "send informations of first api call to do", 0);
        boolean stop = false;
        do {
            try {
                final String msg = (String) this.jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert("LOCAL_Q");
                // execute call or verify resources creation
                stop = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // if api call fails, send again to the same destination
                // to be
                // treated after 5 seconds
                send("LOCAL_Q", "resend call api or resources creation verification to do after 5s", 5000);
            }
        } while (!stop);
    }

    public void send(String dest, final String msg, final long delay) {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(dest, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(msg);
                tm.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, delay);
                return tm;
            }
        });
    }
}
```